# How do factory contracts work? trying to make a factory contract for NFTs

Tags: solidity, factory

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT License
pragma solidity ^0.8.15;

import "./ERC721Creator.sol";

contract MockNFT is ERC721Creator {
    constructor() ERC721Creator("name", "symbol", msg.sender) {}
}
```

How do i wrap to make instances of this through a factory contract?
I want to make a solidity factory contracts that takes just these 2 strings as arguments and mints a new NFT contract

Answer (score 0):

You have to do two things to create factory:

1. Create Factory Contract with such function:

   `function newServiceOffer(string memory text0, string memory text1) external { NewContract newContract = new NewContract(text0, text1); }`
2. Create Template Contract:

Template smart contract has to have constructor if you want to give template smart contract arguments. In this case template smart contract name has to be NewContract.

```
constructor(string memory _text0, string memory _text1) {
        text0 = _text0;
        text1 = _text1;
    }
```

I think you just have to put few arguments inside of constructor, and then replace "name" and "symbol" with arguments given to constructor.